# Почему ставится запятая в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Почему ставится запятая в следующем предложении?

> "То, чем, по мнению некоторых, должны отличаться стражи, — дружелюбие к своим и суровость по отношению к чужим(,) — есть мужество духа, от которого исходит дружелюбное чувство; ведь это и есть та способность души, благодаря которой мы любим".

"Дружелюбие к своим и суровость по отношению к чужим" выделяется тире с двух сторон, потому что это уточнение.

Но почему после "чужим" стоит запятая?

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1. "Перенесенная (вторая) запятая"** закрывает придаточное предложение, то есть относится к структуре предложения (вставка входит в придаточное предложение)

То, чем должны отличаться стражи – **дружелюбие к своим и суровость по отношению к чужим**, – есть мужество духа, от которого исходит дружелюбное чувство; ведь это и есть та способность души, благодаря которой мы любим.

**Вариант 2. Симметрия знаков** (первая запятая ставится для симметрии):

То, чем должны отличаться стражи, – **дружелюбие к своим и суровость по отношению к чужим,**– есть мужество духа, от которого исходит дружелюбное чувство; ведь это и есть та способность души, благодаря которой мы любим.

Comment: В том и вопрос был, что делают две запятые, из которых только на одну можно возложить грамматическую функцию (закрытие оборота). Идея украшения симметрией действительно где-то прописана?

Comment: Alex_ander, на этом форуме  формулировать собственные идеи под видом правил было бы крайней беспечностью, поэтому я могу привести ссылку. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123  Следует, впрочем, заметить, что часто встречается своеобразная «симметрия» знаков (постановка запятой перед вторым тире, если перед первым тире стоит запятая): Когда я стану умирать, — и, верь, тебе не долго ждать, — ты перенесть меня вели в наш сад (Л.);

Comment: Я думаю, что симметричной запятой является первая, а вторая соответствует правилам. У автора вопроса - наоборот,  скобками обозначена вторая запятая, которую надо объяснить.

Comment: Что ж, Розенталь извинений этому не приводит, а описывает как "случающееся", а не "циркулярное" явление (трудно себе представить рекомендацию "добавить для симметрии"), даже "симметрия" у него в кавычках. Объяснение такому явлению видимо, в том, что два тире, превращающие во вставку нечто уже обособленное запятыми (по интонации или иным причинам), добавляются последними к фрагменту, в котором замечено выпадение его из остального по смыслу, в результате имевшиеся запятые остаются.

Comment: Знаете, по-моему, можно всё объяснить просто: пунктуация должна помочь читателю правильно понять текст, а не усложнять его чрезмерной смысловой нагрузкой. При симметрии  запятых вы прочитаете его быстро, а в случае одной запятой остановитесь и будете искать какие-то особые значения, которых нет. И кому это нужно?

Comment: Я лично быстрее прочитаю при минимуме знаков, когда они хотя бы по одному следуют :) Логичнее отбросить один из знаков в возникающей паре при появлении тире, как это делается при появлении основания для точки.

Comment: Вы можете выбрать тот вариант, который вас больше устраивает. Розенталь дает вам такую возможность, и это разумно.  Думаю, что симметрия знаков допускается им как результат наблюдения практики подобных написаний.